# Respecting ObservableObject, but the view is complaining

Tags: swift, observable

I have an ObservableObject described as below:

```swift
class DeviceManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var devices: [Device] = []
    var blM: BlInfo!
    
    init() {
        blM = BlInfo()
        blM.stateDelegate = self
        blM.devicesDelegate = self
    }
}

extension DeviceManager: BlDevicesDelegate {
    func didDiscoverDevice(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Discovered \(String(describing: peripheral.name)) with ID \(peripheral.identifier)")
        if devices.filter({ $0.name == peripheral.name }).count == 0 {
            print("Added \(String(describing: peripheral.name)) with ID \(peripheral.identifier)")
            devices.append(Device(id: peripheral.identifier, name: peripheral.name ?? "Unknown name", peripheral: peripheral))
        }
    }
    
    func didConnect(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        
    }
}

extension DeviceManager: BlStateDelegate {
    func didChangeState(state: CBManagerState) {
        switch(state) {
        case CBManagerState.poweredOn:
            print("BLE is ready")
            blM.discover()
        default:
            print("BLE is not ready")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to show in a view the **Devices List**. I have already created the view, but the compiler is complaining about my object:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var deviceManager: DeviceManager! = DeviceManager()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(deviceManager.devices) { device in
                Text(device.name)
            }.navigationBarTitle("Devices")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The error is

> Generic struct 'ObservedObject' requires that 'DeviceManager?' conform to 'ObservableObject'

Do you have any idea why it is not working? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need optional, ie use

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var deviceManager = DeviceManager()
```

Comment: Thank you! Just assuming... Optional is not observable, right?